# Bootstrap img-circle for embedded Google map in Safari not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

Currently using Bootstrap to build a Wordpress theme. Now, I've embedded a Google Map via jQuery so it loads within a specified div:

```
<div id="map" class="img-responsive img-circle"></div>
```

I've applied img-responsive and img-circle to said div so that the map appears as a circle and is responsive when scaled down across devices. Map is beautiful and works fine and dandy in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari (8.0.8).

It looks something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code is verified on safari,chrome,mozila etc.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    iframe{
        -moz-border-radius:250px;
        -webkit-border-radius:250px;
        -o-border-radius:250px;
        -ms-border-radius:250px;    
        border-radius:250px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="map-image">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3635689.793072721!2d80.8833819!3d27.141237!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x30635ff06b92b791%3A0xd78c4fa1854213a6!2sIndia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1441046961837" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've embedded using jQuery - so not an iframe. And I'm using bootstrap img-responsive and img-circle.

I've also tried your code on Safari, and it's still a square.

Comment: but i checked it in safari before.. after that i sent u.

Answer (score 0):

but i have checked it in safarr.. see attached image
[image]